# Duvidas incremento $i + loop for

Tags: php, estrutura-de-dados, lógica, auto-incremento

Colegas, as vezes me deparo com alguns trechos no código utilizado a variável  $i antes do laço de repetição ($i = 0) e no meio e no final $i++, conforme os exemplos abaixo:

Ex1)

```
$c = count($obj);
$i = 0; //aqui
for ($j = 0; $j < $c; $j++) {

    $matr = $obj[$j]->MATR;
    $nome = trim($obj[$j]->NOME);
    $cd_lot = trim($obj[$j]->LOTACAO);
    $nm_lot = $obj[$j]->DESC_LOTA;
    $regional = $obj[$j]->ESTAB;
    $cargo = $obj[$j]->CARGO;


if (($isAtivo) && (substr($cd_lot, 0, 1) == 'E') ) {
    $arrFolhaOrd[$i] = array();
    $arrFolhaOrd[$i]['nome'] = $nome;
    $arrFolhaOrd[$i]['matr'] = $matr;
    $arrFolhaOrd[$i]['cargo'] = $cargo;
    $i++; //aqui
    $arrFolha1[$matr] = array();
    $arrFolha1[$matr]['nome'] = $nome;
    $arrFolha1[$matr]['cd_lot'] = $cd_lot;
    $arrFolha1[$matr]['nm_lot'] = $nm_lot;

    }
}
```

Ex2:

```
while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
$matr = $linha['matr'];
$cd_lot = trim($linha['cd_lot']);
$ap_freq = $linha['ap_freq'];
if ($matr_ant != $matr){
    $aAtuacao[$matr] = array();
    $i = 0;
    $matr_ant = $matr;
}
$aAtuacao[$matr][$i] = array();
$aAtuacao[$matr][$i]['cd_lot']=$cd_lot;
$aAtuacao[$matr][$i]['ap_freq']=$ap_freq;
$i++;
```

}

Gostaria de umas dicas de como e quando usar auto incremento $i++ e o $i = 0, dentro e fora do loop for  e while.
obrigado

Answer (score 2):

No seu **for** a variável `$i` está sendo utilizando para incrementar o valor quando tiver a condição:

- `($isAtivo) && (substr($cd_lot, 0, 1) == 'E')` for **verdadeira**

Então após o **for** se você quiser saber **quantas** vezes entrou no `if` basta fazer um:

```
echo $i;
```

No seu **while** a variável `i` está sendo utilizada para preencher um **array** enquanto a condição:

- `$matr_ant != $matr` for **falsa**

Então enquanto for igual é criado um novo array na posição `$i` dentro do `$aAtuacao[$matr]` e preenchido com valores. Quando essa condição `$matr_ant != $matr` fica **verdadeira**, ou seja, for diferente então o índice `$i` é resetado para *zero* e começa os *arrays* da posição inicial.

A variável `$i` é muito utilizada porque é uma abreviação da palavra ***i***ncrement, ou seja, sempre que você precisa contar ou acessar posições em arrays é muito comum declarar essa variável para fazer o **controle.**

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que tudo depende da operação que você deseja realizar.

Normalmente em laços de repetição While declaramos a variável $i = 0 (ou outro valor) antes de começar o laço de repetição e dentro desta repetição a gente pode incrementar ou decrementar, como já falei, tudo vai depender da operação que você deseja realizar, você pode até mesmo precisar mudar o valor dela durante o traço de repetição para evitar um loop infinito por exemplo.

Exemplo: Somando de 1 até 10.

```
$i = 0;
$soma = 0;
while ($i != 10) {
    $soma = $soma + $i;
    $i++;
}
echo $soma;
```

E em laços de repetição For podemos declarar a variável $i = 0 antes do laço de repetição ou diretamente quando mencionamos o For, neste tipo de operação não recomendo mudar o valor da variável $i durante o laço de repetição. Este é bastante utilizado para percorrer Arrays.

Exemplo: Percorrendo um vetor e declaração dentro da variável no For, percorre os valores do vetor de 0 até o tamanho do vetor.

```
for ($i = 0; i < $vetor.length; i++){
    echo $vetor[i];
}
```

Recomendo for e foreach para percorrer Arrays, vetores e matrizes.
While, Repeat para outras operações.

Confira este artigo: http://feloliveira.com.br/blog/estruturas-de-repeticao-em-php-while-do-while-for-e-foreach/